# shell script to get details about sudo commands executed by any user in a linux machine

Tags: shell, terminal

The details like User,Command,
Current_Working_Directory,
Teletype_Terminal, etc .. should be obtained for all the users who executed **sudo**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get some useful info from this link :
[stackoverflow](https://superuser.com/questions/309434/how-to-view-command-history-of-another-user-in-linux)

you can use `tail /var/log/auth.log | grep username` to get the `sudo` history !!

Hope it helps.